# Civilization 5 view - show resources on map

Tags: civilization-5

I see a view on the web where in Civilization 5 you can see the resources on the map by default.  How do I enable that?  For example, in my view, I just see the map and don't see the resources at all.

Here is a site with that view.
http://www.nohighscores.com/2011/08/30/civilization-5-game-diary-ode-to-oda-nobunaga-part-5-turns-401-466/